# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Hi guys if you can help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

This error notes:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, title, bodyText, icon}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

My code snippet:

```js
  if (cards) {
    const filteredCards = cards.filter((card: { title: string }) => {
      return card.title.toLowerCase();
    });
    return filteredCards;
  }
```

console.log(cards)
gives:

```
cards (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

if I'm using an array there as the error notes, isn't this redundant?

I'm kind of confused.

Comment: What does the individual array item (card) look like? {id, title, content} ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return an array of JSX or an array of strings. I guess you meant to get the lowerCase of titles. For that, you should be using `map` instead of `filter`. Currently `filteredCards` is an array of JSON in the format same as an item `cards`.

Try like this.

```
  if (cards) {
    const filteredCards = cards.map((card: { title: string }) => {
      return card.title.toLowerCase();
    });
    return filteredCards;
  }
```